# Fractional power of batch matrices using numpy, scipy or torch

Tags: numpy, matrix

Is there a way to calculate fractional power of a batch/3d array (e.g. shape : 4*3*3) using any scientific computing libraries? 
I've come across scipy.linalg fractional_matrix_power, but it doesn't seem to work for batch matrices. Currently, I'm using list comprehension to iterate over the batch, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

Is there any workaround or libraries to parallelize the task?

```
D_nsqrt = fractional_matrix_power(D, -0.5)
```

Code above throws error : ValueError: expected square array_like input.
But following works fine:

```
D_nsqrt = fractional_matrix_power(D[0], -0.5)
```

Shape of D : 4*3*3

Comment: That function uses `"Matrix functions that use Pade approximation with inverse scaling and squaring."`  In other words, code that works with a square matrix, one that has, among other things an inverse.  I'd suggest doing some research on Pade approximation, and decide for yourself whether that's `parallelizable`.

Comment: In `numpy` you get the biggest speed gains if you move a loop with many small iterations into compiled code (i.e. use the `ndarray` methods).  It's harder to get much of an improvement when doing a few iterations on a complex task.

Comment: Hey @hpaulj could you please elaborate your second comment, i.e. move a loop with many small iterations. An example would be great!